# Determine the definite integral of first derivative multiplied with second derivative

Tags: calculus

$\int_0^1 f'(x)f''(x) dx$

When $f'(0) = 3$ and $f'(1) = 2$

I tried doing intergration by parts but I got stuck in a loop.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the derivative of $(f'(x))^2$?

Comment: $2f'(x) f''(x)$ so I could write it as the integral of the derivative of $\frac{f'(x)^2}{2}$ which would give me $2 - 3 = 1$ or did I mess up

Comment: $\frac{2^2}{2}-\frac{3^2}{2} = -\frac{5}{2}$, surely?

Comment: yeah my brain stopped working there for a moment

Answer (score 1):

Try integration by change of variable. Set $u = f'(x),\ du = f''(x)\ dx$, then your integral becomes :
$$
\int_3^2 u\ du
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_0^1 f'(x)f''(x) \, dx = \int_{f'(0)}^{f'(1)} u\,du.$$